# JavasScript fetch/get Request / 2 times / 3 times click button

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api, jsonobjectrequest, undefined-variable

I am relative new to JavaScript.I have a "strange" problem: I have two input fields which when I click the sndBtn (clickEventListener), then 3 functions are called, all with a fetch/get requests and then give a JSON object back.

But when iI click the button, first I get an undefined object, when I click a second time, I get the first object... third the second object etc... so I have to click 3 times and then it works.

Maybe someone can explain how I get it to work on the first click?

Thanks

```
let vonPlz;
let nachPlz;
let vonOrt;
let nachOrt; 
let km;
let kilometer;
let sendBtn;
let vonLon;
let vonLat;
let nachLon;
let nachLat;
let vonJson;
let nachJson;


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event)  {
    vonPlz = document.getElementById("vonPlz");
        nachPlz = document.getElementById("nachPlz");
        vonOrt = document.getElementById("vonOrt");
        nachOrt = document.getElementById("nachOrt");
        km = document.getElementById("km");
        sendBtn = document.getElementById("sendBtn");
    
    
    sendBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        
        getReqVonPlz(vonPlz.value);
        getReqNachPlz(nachPlz.value);
        
        console.log(vonJson[0].display_name);
        console.log(nachJson[0].display_name);
        
        vonLat = vonJson[0].lat;
        vonLon = vonJson[0].lon;
        nachLat = nachJson[0].lat;
        nachLon = nachJson[0].lon;
        
        postReqKm(vonLat, vonLon, nachLat, nachLon);
        console.log(kilometer);
        vonOrt.innerHTML = vonJson[0].display_name;
        nachOrt.innerHTML = nachJson[0].display_name;
        km.innerHTML = kilometer;
    })

   
});

 
    
async function getReqVonPlz(plz){
    await fetch("https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&country=de&postalcode=" +plz , {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        }
        })
        .then((response) =>  response.json())
        .then((json) => {vonJson = json});
         
        
}

async function getReqNachPlz(plz){
    await fetch("https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&country=de&postalcode=" +plz , {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        }
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {nachJson = json});

        
}


async function postReqKm(vonLat, vonLon, nachLat, nachLon){
    await fetch("https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/directions/driving-car", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
        coordinates: [[vonLon,vonLat],[nachLon,nachLat]],
       
    }),
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        "Authorization": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    }
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) =>  {kilometer = json.routes[0].summary.distance});
}
```

first I didn't add the async-await functions? When I tested it with only one function it worked, now I do the async and await on all 3 functions, but I have to click 3 times.

So I think the problem is somewhere with that, but I am really new to that.

Answer (score 1):

javascript is async, which means it wont wait for function execution to complete. Hence you need to enforce to make your function synchronised.

**Current behaviour of your code:**

execute getReqVonPlz w/o waiting

execute getReqNachPlz  w/o waiting

execute postReqKm w/o waiting

**Desired behaviour :**

execute getReqVonPlz and wait

execute getReqNachPlz and wait

execute postReqKm based on the result of above function results

there are several ways you can accomplish this, preferred ones are:

1. Promises Chaining
2. Using awaits or await-all

I'll demonstrate the example of await in this answer

```
var [vonJson, nachJson] = await Promise.all([getReqVonPlz(vonPlz.value), getReqNachPlz(nachPlz.value)]);
vonJson = vonJson.json();
nachJson = nachJson.json();
//process your vonJson & nachJson
var res = await postReqKm(vonLat, vonLon, nachLat, nachLon);
//process your res
```

make your functions return promise eg.

```
function getReqNachPlz(plz){
return fetch("https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&country=de&postalcode=" +plz , {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    }
    });
```

}

Comment: Ahh ok make sense thank you so much!!!
I have to learn more about it.
Now i get the error that the click event func is not async.... and when i do call a new async function in the click event it gets me a error with the vonJson.json() ...

but i have to go to bed now and have a look at this tomorrow.